# MySQL query to order by time and return n rows after specific id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a table in my database (versions: MariaDB 10.3.17, MySQL 5.7) as follows:

```
id      name        timestamp
-----------------------------
154875  AXC         154875869
362574  RTB         154875800
962548  MNV         154875969
365847  XRT         154875123
...
```

what I need:

1. sort the rows on timestamp descending
2. then return 24 rows after (below) where id=something

for example for id=962548, the first 3 rows of the expected output will be:

```
id      name        timestamp
-----------------------------
154875  AXC         154875869
362574  RTB         154875800
365847  XRT         154875123
```

how to implement it in MySQL?

Comment: add your required ouput in table format

Comment: @Fahmi added to the post!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the offset of a particular row in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051578/how-can-i-get-the-offset-of-a-particular-row-in-mysql)

Comment: @LeviCole no, because here the values of id column are not ordered, a row which is below another row may have larger or smaller id, no rule! but they will be ordered based on timestamp

Comment: Are the timestamps unique?

Comment: not necessarily, otherwise I could just focus on `timestamp` column, not `id` column!

Comment: Then *sort the rows on timestamp descending* is not enough because it does not provide a unique result.

Comment: the result is unique because `id` values are unique

Comment: The result is not defined if you don't sort **also** by id.

Comment: oops! you are right :) so we can sort descending on id as well. not a big deal!

Comment: For your sample data, if you *sort the rows on timestamp descending* there is no row below 365847, because 154875123 is the min timestamp.

Comment: @forpas I had made a mistake in my expected output table. they were ascending not descending! I fixed the issue

Comment: Fine, then my 1st query works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v5HnGZoB929ZnQ2RiG6iV7/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the query that returns the row with id = *something* to the table under your conditions:

```
select t.*
from tablename t 
inner join (select * from tablename where id = 365847) c
on t.timestamp < c.timestamp or (t.timestamp = c.timestamp and t.id < c.id)
order by t.timestamp desc, t.id desc
limit 24
```

but I'm not sure what you mean by *below*, so maybe you want the opposite order:

```
select t.*
from tablename t 
inner join (select * from tablename where id = 365847) c
on t.timestamp > c.timestamp or (t.timestamp = c.timestamp and t.id > c.id)
order by t.timestamp desc, t.id desc
limit 24
```

Comment: why are you inner joining? can't it be achieved by inner queries?

Comment: There are 2 conditions: t.timestamp > c.timestamp and (t.timestamp = c.timestamp and t.id > c.id). If I used subqueries I would have to repeat the subquery `select * from tablename where id = 365847` twice so I can refer to its columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select elements that have the timestamp value greater than your id timestamp, using a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp>(select timestamp 
                 from table
                 where id = 'current_id') 
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 24;
```

Comment: timestamp values are not unique and so `WHERE timestamp>(select timestamp from table where id = 'current_id')` can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'd query it something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE timestamp >= (SELECT timestamp FROM tab WHERE id = 154875)
AND id <> 154875
ORDER BY timestamp DESC,  id DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: timestamp values are not unique and so `timestamp >= (SELECT timestamp FROM tab WHERE id = 154875)` can be wrong

Comment: @Soheil you are right but I guess you can not get more accuracy out of it if you want it to be ordered by the timestamp. A question could be if your id might have the correct order already, so you can use the id. I'd expect it to be unique and in the order of insertion of the rows.

Comment: @Soheil - Then the problem specification is incomplete.  Perhaps your step 1 should say `ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC`?

Comment: The main challenge is walking through a composite index.  There are at least 2 more ways to formulate it.  The "row constructor" approach `(ts,id)<(i.ts,123)` may be the best but _only_ for newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: @RickJames yes, you are right. `ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC`, both are required